# רָקִיאַע or רָקִיַע

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, grammar-dikduk, torah-reading, pronunciation

The [*Minchas Shay* at the beginning of *B'reshis*](https://www.sefaria.org/Minchat_Shai_on_Torah%2C_Genesis.1.6.1) cites a dispute whether the word 'רָקִיעַ' (and likewise for other words with a furtive *patach*) is pronounced as רָקִיאַע or as רָקִיַע, that is, with a glottal stop or without before the *patach*. Does anyone know of a modern source that indicates the appropriate custom, or any indication of the most common custom (among those who would pronounce רָקִיאַע differently from רָקִיַע)?

Comment: msh210, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks for the detailed question! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: See Guy Deutscher's The Unfolding of Language, page 285.

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1106

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22224&st=&pgnum=69 http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21293&st=&pgnum=101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "סימנים" edition of תנ״ך, edited by שמואל מאיר ריאחי / Shmuel Meir Riachi (of Jerusalem) and published by Feldheim in 2006, includes in its prefatory list of features (in feature 5) the following explanation (in my own translation from the Hebrew):

> The letters ח,‎ ע, and pronounced הּ, when they come at the end of a word with a פתח, are called "stolen פתח"…. In the Sephardic communities they are accustomed to add the letter י before it…, and in the Ashkenazic communities they are accustomed to add the letter א before it….

He cites no source.

Answer (score 4):

Sepharads (and more precisely tuniasian) pronounces Raki-Ya and when the letter before the patah' is a waw then we pronounce wa (like rou-wah').
You can see the Tikoun soferim Ich Matsliah' for further informations

Comment: allced, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your Tunisian perspective to this question! Please consider clicking register, above, to create your account. This will give you access to all of mi.yodeya's features and will allow you to take full credit for your contributions.

Answer (score 1):

The way I heard it in Yeshiva, it's ru-ach and ko-ach; thus, raki-a'; also, gavo-ah and elo-ah (not gavohah or elohah, though I think Lakewood's BMG spells it as such; the rebbe of mine who told us this was a product of BMG and admitted it was a problem.)  I'm assuming the ayins are the same as ches's and heh's.

Has anyone heard otherwise?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify which of the 2 possible pronunciations you mean by "ru-ach" and "raki-a'"? Do you mean that there's an aleph (glottal stop) before the patach, or that the patach is pronounced on the vav (w) / yod?

Answer (score 0):

In most dikduk sefarim it states that by throat letters (aleph hey ches and ayin) if they are the last letter  of a word with a pasach under them they are read as if pasach alef precedes them. I'm sure you know this. This being the case, the correct way would be rakiaa with a pasach alef. Also one of the subrules of this klal is that the word becomes milel meaning the stress is on the beginning of the word. In rakia we say raKIah not rakiAH so I would take that as yet another proof. I will check the Minchas Shai again because I must have forgotten it. Also, who is to say that the ayin does not get pronounced even if there is an alef? Tishma has an ayin at the end with no nikud. Do you say it like it had no ayin or do you need to make the glottal stop anyway. I would assume yes. If so, it  would be very hard to diffrentiate between rakia with an alef or without.

Answer (score 0):

i cannot provide written sources, but i can provide Sephardim reading those pesuqim in question.

First one by Rabbi Yossef Benarroch ZT'L (don't know what flavor of Sepharad)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgrNU2PNYLQ

This website is called Pizmonim, and if you click on the link it will take you to a page of Torah readings. There is one for Bereishith and it had something like 4 recorded versions.

http://www.pizmonim.com/section.php?maqam=Pentateuch

Take a listen.