# Why is a chet with a patach pronounced differently?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, aleph-bet-letters

Why is a chet with a patach at the end of a word pronounced "ACH" and not "CHA"? Example: מָשִׁיחַ

Comment: As noted in an answer, this is not quite worded correctly. Also, the title should specify that you are referring to the end of the word.

Comment: @SethJ "a chet with a patach at **the end** of a word" ?

Comment: @BA, "the _title_ should specify..."

Comment: Does anyone think this is in scope?

Comment: Astonishing, I think, that questions pertaining to the Hebrew language and to Israelite history are considered tangential to Judaism. I've read the FAQ, I'm just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the question is why it is *spelt* differently, and not why it is pronounced differently at all. If you wanted to say *meshicha*, you certainly could. That would be a different word, of course, though a related one. It would be spelt משיחה.

For words that end in -*ach*, orthographic convention has us conclude them with the *chet*. This is also the case for words ending in -*'a* (such as רקיע) and in -*ah*, where the final ה is consonantal (such as אלוהּ).

The reason for all of these is that the final vowel/consonant combination is not preceded by a phonological *alef*, but by a rounding off of the previous vowel. Hence, *mashi(y)ach*, *raqi(y)a* and *elo(w)ah*.

Comment: Not all agree with your last paragraph http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2313/759

Comment: @doubleaa, that may be, but Shimon is correct.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter if I'm wrong: the issue isn't how people pronounce *alefs* and elided vowels today vs. how they did in the past, but that people did (and do) differentiate between them, that such a differentiation is manifested here, and that its represented orthographically. That last line was really just by way of an example, though different communities pronounce things in different ways.